# Is there a website that records the moves of a chess game in video or gif format, and also allows illegal moves?

Tags: chess-variants, illegal-move

I've wanted to record some chess games in 2d video or gif form from a version that I made that has different rules, but it won't allow me to import it because it has illegal moves. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Welcome to the Chess SE, joca9!   When you say "...it won't allow...", could you elaborate on what "it" this is? Which website(s) and/or software program(s) have you used, so far?

Comment: @CharlesRockafellor I mean that when I try to make the gif in say, the chess.com or lichess, it wont allow for the moves to be made because they are illegal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. gfychess.com allow you to import PGN files and convert to GIF with some illegal moves, such as moving pawns two spaces anywhere on the board, or taking your own pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, chess.com has its feature of producing gifs from PGNs or using game links. You can find the option [here](https://www.chess.com/gifs).